# size_of returning wrong answer

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php to get some data from mysql table. The table returns the right results however because the table has many columns, i thought that i could create a for loop for this and save all my values as `val1`, `val2` etc. I am first using a while loop as there can be several rows:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
    for($i = 1; $i < sizeof($row1); $i++) {
        $val.$i = $row1[$i];
    }
```

However for some reason sizeof($row1) returns 40 whereas i have only 18 columns in that table.

I think `$val.$i = $row1[$i];` is not the right way to declare a variable?

I know i would have made a silly mistake, but i am unable to figure it out. :S

Comment: If you have 18 numbered columns in your database, you should review your database structure.

Comment: @ChtistopeD: No, I just have one at the moment!

Comment: do you think this is right: `$val.$i = $row1[$i];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to specify the result type:

```
mysql_fetch_array($sql2, MYSQL_NUM);
```

From the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both
>   associative and number indices.

Comment: This worked for my, but i just realised that my problem has to do with `$val.$i = $row1[$i];` instead, any clues?

Comment: @Namit why does your count start from 1? shouldn't it be 0 instead?

Comment: I want to start getting the data from the second column, as the first is just the key.

Comment: You could do `${'val'.$i}` which would create `$val1`, `$val2`, etc., but it's not recommended. Better to just do an array `$val[$i]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are also maybe  some duplicate values from your $sql2  , 
use DISTINCT keyword in your Select.

Comment: that would not affect the number of results in a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing comments from umopdn [at] msn [dawt] com on the docs sizeof page:

> a) Always use PHP's internal routines to iterate through objects of
>   various types...Instead of interpreting your code to loop through
>   them, they use their own internal routines which are much faster.
>   (This is why foreach () will run faster than manual interation)
>
> ...
>
> c) I agree with PixEye's remarks on sizeof().  In PHP it is just an
>   alias for the true function count().  It has other meanings logically
>   in other languages rather than the number of elements in an object. 
>   This should be avoided as it may confuse developers transitioning to
>   PHP from other languages.

You should be using count() in favor of sizeof(), but that negated by the fact that you can, and should, use foreach() instead of for().