# Declare variables on the fly using for loop

Tags: php

I am not sure if its a good idea, but i just thought it would be less tedious and much easier to declare variables on the fly using a for loop:

`$val.$i = $row1[$i];`. Now after trying this, this obviously isn't the right thing to do. Is there anyway i can improve this and not declare separate variables.

Maybe this will give a clearer picture:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $val.$i = $row1[$i];
 }
```

Now i want to achieve `$val1` using `$val.$i`.

Comment: What you're basically doing is this: `$val[$i] = $row1[$i];`, which doesn't really achieve anything.. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Surely better to use your existing array directly rather than create a whole series of meaningless variables, and as I'm guessing you're reading $row1 from a database, then this will be subject to change if ever you change the structure of the underlying database

Comment: The interesting part is that s/he is already using the best answer to the question, **an array**.

Comment: $i is being run using a for loop, so i thought by declaring $val.$i it will create $val1, which is a horrible idea i know. So i am wondering if i can achieve that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have posted, using an associative or 0-based array would be a far better implementation, but you can implement the solution just as you have requested using PHP's variable variable names:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
{
  ${"val".$i} = "this is value " . $i;
}    

echo "$val1<br />$val2<br />$val3<br />$val4<br />$val5";
```

Will output:

```
this is value 1
this is value 2
this is value 3
this is value 4
this is value 5
```

Comment: `val` should be enclosed within quotes, otherwise PHP converts it to a constant...

Comment: based on above answer by @BenM for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) 
{
  echo ${"val".$i} = "this is value " . $i."<br>";
}

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can define variables by name.

Example:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$$foo = 'baz';
echo $bar; // echoes 'baz'
```

So in your case, it would look like:

```
$var = 'val'.$i;
$$var = $arr[$i];
```

Why you would do that, I have no idea.
A better system (imho) is to use `list()` construct:

```
list($val1, $val2, $val3) = $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an associative array and then use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
$arr = array();
// ...
$arr[$val.$i] = $row1[$i];
// ...
extract($arr);
```

Mind you, it will probably be better to use the array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to get all the data you are reading from your database into one easy to access place. All you need to do is shove each row into an array:

```
$allTheThings[] = $row1;
```

You'll end up with a two dimensional array where the first key is the row number and the second key is the column number.

Comment: Uhm, I'm pretty sure s/he already has such an array. At the very most, I would use `array_values()` instead of reinventing the wheel. :)

Comment: @Christian The OP has a one dimensional array with one row of data in it. Based on his [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490858/size-of-returning-wrong-answer), this is from `mysql_fetch_array`, which returns one row at a time. To get a complete two dimensional array it is necessary to build it on the fly as I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting full picture of what you are trying to do, but to convert arrays into objects you would do this:

```
$val = (object) $row1;
```

Comment: Edited my question, maybe that will help